# I changed my WordPress password using phpmyadmin, now I have a database error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, encryption, phpmyadmin

So here's what happened. The website was working just fine but I inherited the website from someone else and the previous designer failed to provide the login information. So, I needed to reset the admin password. I accessed the WordPress database using phpMyAdmin following the instructions at http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin.

I did notice something on the 'wp_users' page that I thought was interesting. Every password starts with a '$P$B' except for the one that I just changed which has no special characters like $ and uses just letters and numbers. I selected MD5 from the dropdown when resetting my password so I am wondering if I need to use a different encryption type. I tried SHA1 just to be safe but that wasn't it and it doesn't look like it could be any of the other dropdown options.

Comment: I wonder what WP does. See the "normal" [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) output - only DES and Extended DES are reported to not start with a `$`. `$P` isn't from normal `crypt` at all. (Maybe change the password from *within* WP?)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I failed to mention that the previous designer had not provided the admin information and I wasn't sure how else I could reset the password.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is reset the password, then MD5 is perfectly fine. WordPress implements the [portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (phpass), and uses MD5-based salted portable hashes to store passwords. The `$P$` comes into it as WordPress forces this at the start of all encrypted passwords as an identifier (see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/class-phpass.php#L101)).

If you just use the default MD5 in the database, once you login (and it will let you login!), WordPress will rehash automatically using phpass.

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining that. So that means my database error is due to something else? I guess it's a little hard for me to believe because the website was fine and now it's done.

Comment: @giwook What exactly is the database error that you're getting? Is this WordPress saying there's a database error, or is this an issue with MySQL when you try to update the password (presumably through phpMyAdmin)?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is create a new user with the password you want to have in the end and then copy the hash from the new user to the user you wanted to change. This way no matter what encryption is used, you will use the same type.

Ideally wordpress should be smart enough about this, but the way I propose will ensure that you will have the appropriate password.

Answer (score 0):

Just like that, the website is fine. I didn't touch anything and came back to it this morning so it looks like it may have been something server-side?